# How do you implement a Makefile that remembers the last build target?

Tags: makefile, target, gnu-make

Let's say you have a Makefile with two pseudo-targets, 'all' and 'debug'. The 'debug' target is meant to build the same project as 'all', except with some different compile switches (like -ggdb, for example). Since the targets use different compile switches, you obviously need to rebuild the entire project if you switch between the two. But GNUmake doesn't naturally recognize this.

So if you type `make all` you'll get

```
Building ...
...
```

Then if you type `make debug`, you get

```
make: Nothing to be done for `debug'.
```

So my question is: **how do you implement a clean solution in the Makefile to notice that the last build used a different pseudo-target, or different compile switches, than the one you want currently?** If they are different, the Makefile would rebuild everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the build products into different directory trees (whilst keeping one copy of the source of course). That way you are always just a short compile from an up-to-date build, be it debug or release (or even others). No possibility of confusion either.

**EDIT**

Sketch of the above.

```
src := 1.c 2.c 3.c
bare-objs := ${src:%.c=%.o}
release-objs := ${bare-objs:%=Release/%}
debug-objs := ${bare-objs:%=Debug/%}

Release/prog: ${release-objs}
Debug/prog: ${debug-objs}

${release-objs}: Release/%.o: %.c # You gotta lurve static pattern rules
    gcc -c $< -o $@

${debug-objs}: Debug/%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

Release/prog Debug/prog:
    gcc $^ -o $@

.PHONY: all
all: Release/prog ; echo $@ Success

.PHONY: debug
debug: Debug/prog ; echo $@ Success
```

(Disclaimer: not tested, nor even run through make.)

There you go. It's even `-j` safe so you can do `make -j5 all debug`. There is a lot of obvious boiler plate just crying out for tidying up.

Comment: Pretty straightforward. I can imagine this works in most situations. I'd still prefer to build to only one target if possible.

Comment: @Elliot: In this case, when building the `debug` target, first delete the `all` target. Still less error prone than having one of two targets in a tree. Are you sure you are good enough to always know which target the tree currently holds?

Comment: I've found the simplest way to do this is with recursive make calls. E.g.
`debug:
        @$(MAKE) all TARGET_DIR="$(DEBUG_DIR)" FLAGS="-ggdb"`

Comment: @Elliot: I'm not a fan of recursive make for various reasons. There are always other mechanisms (target specific variables `debug: TARGET_DIR := debugdir/`; or indirection `TARGET-debug := debugdir/` then use `${TARGET-$@}` in a recipe (I prefer this latter formulation)).

Comment: @bobbogo: I'm having difficulty implementing either of those options. My debug target is simply `debug : $(OUT_FILE)` because it depends on an executable which depends on a bunch of object files. Setting target-specific variables for `debug` doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure how to do indirection on a whole bunch of different targets.

Comment: @Elliot: O.K., I've added a sketch. Do you still prefer to build only one target?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping variant sets of object files (as in bobbogo's solution) is probably the best way, but if for some reason you don't want to do that, you can use empty files as markers, to indicate which way you last built the executable:

```
%-marker:
        @rm -f $(OBJECTS) *-marker
        @touch $@

debug: GCCFLAGS += -ggdb

debug: SOMEOTHERFLAG = WHATEVER

all debug: % : %-marker
        @echo making $@
        @$(MAKE) -S GCCFLAGS='$(GCCFLAGS)' SOMEOTHERFLAG='$(SOMEOTHERFLAG)' main
```

There are other variants on this idea; you could have a small file containing the flag settings, which the makefile would build and `include`. That would be clever, but not really any cleaner than this.

Comment: Wow...excellent and clever. I'll have to look into some of that Makefile syntax!

Answer (score 1):

The only clean solution is to incorporate the difference into the target names.
E.g. you can define a variable `$(DEBUG)` and consistently use it in all targets that depend on the compile step.